# Error hosting web API in Blazor server web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, asp.net-web-api-routing

We have an existing .NET 5.0 Blazor web application. I have added an ASP.NET Core Web API to the same project because I want to provide a REST interface to external consumers. When I request `http://localhost:5000/stripe/customerwebhook`, I get a `404 not found` error. What could I be missing?

My CustomerWebhookController API class looks like the following:

```
[Route("stripe/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomerWebhookController : ControllerBase
{        
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {            
            return Ok();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            OnConfiguringServices(services);
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(serviceProvider =>
            {
              var uriHelper = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
              return new HttpClient
              {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
              };
            });
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddHubOptions(o =>
            {
                o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
            });
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApplicationIdentityDbContext identityDbContext)
        {
            OnConfiguring(app, env);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.Use((ctx, next) =>
                {
                    return next();
                });
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you request the page in a browser?

You might want to remove that [HttpPost].

Comment: Thank you @NeilW, I was requesting the page in browser, requesting the endpoint in postman worked.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand your code, that won't work in the browser at all, since those by default send GET requests. There is no route for [HttpGet] in your code, so you get an 404.